# Create a function to calculate the number of songs played for a given day and city

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

It will require two parameters:

day of the week
name of the city
In the function, use a variable to store the rows from the original table, where:

'day' column value is equal to the day parameter
'city' column value is equal to the city parameter
Apply consecutive filtering with logical indexing.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/datasets/music_project_en.csv')
df.rename(columns=({'  userID':'user_id','Track':'track', 'artist':'artist', 'genre':'genre', '  
City  ':'city', 'time':'time', 'Day':'day'}), inplace=True,)
df['track'] = df['track'].fillna('unknown')
df['genre'] = df['genre'].fillna('unknown')
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
df.sort_values(by = ['genre'],inplace = True)
df['genre'].unique()
print(df['genre'])
def replace_wrong_genres(wrong_genres, correct_genre):
   for genre in df:
     genre.replace(wrong_genres, correct_genre)
replace_wrong_genres('hip', 'hiphop')
replace_wrong_genres('hop', 'hiphop')
replace_wrong_genres('hip-hop', 'hiphop')
dfspringfield = df.query("city == 'Springfield'")
dfshelbyville = df.query("city == 'Shelbyville'")
dfspringfield_mon = dfspringfield.query("day == 'Monday'")
dfspringfield_wed = dfspringfield.query("day == 'Wednesday'")
dfspringfield_fri = dfspringfield.query("day == 'Friday'")
dfshelbyville_mon = dfshelbyville.query("day == 'Monday'")
dfshelbyville_wed = dfshelbyville.query("day == 'Wednesday'")
dfshelbyville_fri = dfshelbyville.query("day == 'Friday'")
def number_tracks(day, city )
```

So Im building a function that takes the day column and city column of the dataset and returns the sum of the amount of music tracks with those two parameters in mind. The code above is what if done so far to clean the dataset up. Very new to pandas so any help building this function would be much appreciated.

Comment: look at `groupby`

Comment: Consider making a minimal reproducible example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that each row in the df dataframe is a music track

```
df.groupby(['day','city']).size()
```